# Should I push contentModel.xml to GitHub repository?

Tags: xml, ide, rider

I am trying to bring a local Git branch up-to-date with the current master branch. The local had been set aside for some time, so naturally we have many merge errors. One of these is about the contentModel.xml file.

Is the contentModel.xml file specific to the user environment, or to the project structure? This will determine if I should use the GitHub version or the local version, or try to manually merge them.

Note: We recently switched from Visual Studio 2015 to JetBrains Rider 17.3. I have been unable to determine which IDE actually created the file, or if it is needed by both. We also do switch back to VS occasionally to work on designer files, so we need to maintain that backward compatibility in working with this file.

Anyone have some guidance on this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [JetBrains Rider Support Question](https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000661950/comments/115000538984):

> The contentModel.xml file is auto-generated by Rider and can safely be ignored for source control reasons.